# strip special character except delimiter (.) from text string

Tags: python, pandas

I have an "amount" array that looks like this.

```
array([139, 828, 240, 69, 189, 89, 101.15, 95.2, 79, 119, 588, 1308, 59,
       107.1, 199.2, 126.75, 186.75, 156.75, 141.75, 99, 49.9, 110.25,
       89.9, 182.75, 610.9, 270, 207, 100, 177, 9.7, 14.5, 6.95, 5.05,
       1.3, 4.4, 22.6, 6.9, 16.95, 10.25, 7.25, 63.5, 30.55, 99.4, 1.05,
       4.55, 75.8, 13.15, 49.2, 98.15, 39.1, "'0.450000", 99.2, 17.6,
       55.75, 22.55, 14.1, 9.25, 40.4, 7.75, 7.2, 20.9, 2.45, 8.65, 8.3,
       17.55, 12.4, 2.65, 95.65, 15.9, 28.9, 2.25, 23.05, 27, 11.9, 52.7,
       1.2, 8.9, "'0.350000", 20.25, 167.8, 417, 79.2, 1279.25, 267, 297,
       58.65, 116.1, 444, 25, 120, 45.4, 238, 144, 14400, 990.1, 474,
       359.4, 2028, 118, 237, 113, 478.8, 537, 384, 136.1, 250.8, 684,
       299.4, 239, 39.9, 185, 713.05, 130, 168, 312.85, 479.4, 101, 357,
       598.8, 300, 40, 149.7, 579.3, 327, 229, 170, 2976, 534, 1.75, 1.1,
       3.95, 3.55, 31, 36.35, 29.9, 25.85, 23.35, 3.7, 53.4, 62.95, 91.6,
       14.7, 18.25, 45.8, 5.5, 23.2, 20.3, 71.3, 92, 9.3, 11.05, 37.45,
       2.5, 20.1, 84.85, 3, 3.1, "'0.650000", 7.35, 103.6, 7.8, 62, 25.25,
       47.5, 7.85, 15.5, 9.1, 14.05, 6.2, 13.6, 4.5, 7.6, 52, 8.95, 9.45,
       352.8, 507, 714, 470.4, 1548, 179.7, 335.6, 3000, 291, 1014, 354,
       234, 594, 831, 390, 213, 414, 13800, 80, 564, 1799.1, 1069.2,
       786.6, 294, 225, 1200, 147, 8.6, 795.3, 3.6, 9.75, 43.9, 36.1, 7.3,
       3.05, 54.7, 86.95, 5.25, 3.4, 3.2, 4.9, 94, "'0.600000", 2.6,
       52.25, 3.9, 77.7, 12.05, 14.9, 1.8, 8.05, 42.85, 24.95,
       "'0.500000", 29.45, 35.6, 12.2, 1574.4, 573.5, 387, 1609.2, 627,
       324, 5400, 744, 597, 530.65, 961.2, 1177.2, 708, 1285.2, 2374.8,
       249.95, 720, 4.1, 20, 103.35, 32.05, 7.7, 48.7, 14.95, 10.2, 20.65,
       10.8, 14, 118.2, 32.7, 58.75, 691.2, 1046.4, 1198.8, 63.2, 662.4,
       509.05, 1086.6, 870, 948, 853.2, 1194, 570, 44.6, 15.95, 3.25,
       60.7, 124.8, 110.5, 10.95, "'0.900000", 12.8, 112.45, 83.3, 19.1,
       1.85, 16.35, 49.1, "'0.300000", 54.25, 8.5, 5, 20.7, "'0.800000",
       36.05, 21.1, 6.65, 10.1, 14.25, 11.55, 8.15, 8.25, 2.95,
       "'0.100000", 18.6, 3.45, 4.15, 17.1, 64.9, 13.2, 34, 32.5, 2.15,
       39.5, 23.3, 54.35, 110, 7.65, 10.65, 61.55, 5.75, 12.35, 529.2,
       548.9, 774, 233, 1189.2, 1188, 17.3, 20.4, 27.2, 17.45, 60.1, 5.55,
       59.05, 9, 37.15, 77.1, 30.65, 77.3, 17.75, 45.9, 74.45, 15.3,
       51.65, 33.35, "'0.750000", 51.55, 27.7, 17.8, 4.6, 1.45, 4.95, 2.7,
       10.5, 12.1, 9.2, 12.7, 10.75, 21.05, 119.35, 44.4, 10.05, 4.85,
       894, 585, 1356, 749.75, 1728, 158, 540, 19750, 907.2, 23.45, 37.75,
       9.95, 6.45, 53.7, 13.75, 6.7, 21.4, 26.5, 10.15, 6.75, "'0.950000",
       7.55, 1, 18.95, 24.75, 5.35, 6.8, 12.3, 14.75, 40.25, 12.25, 38.05,
       23.85, 52.45, 23.9, 7.45, 141.35, 22.7, 1494.25, 815.05, 419.4,
       1068, 1248, 528, 47.2, 149, 718.8, 15.75, 5.2, 18.05, 11.2, 41.45,
       10.4, 5.45, 44.45, 2.2, 21.55, 19.7, 46.15, 5.1, 112.1, 16, 7.5,
       8.8, 9.05, 12.55, 1.6, 21, 19.35, 19.25, 4.75, 1922.4, 1428, 178,
       411.6, 4.45, 43.15, 17.15, 2.05, 33.3, 21.7, 23.7, "'0.200000",
       20.55, 51.6, 10.3, 3.85, 4.05, 9.9, 17.5, 114.4, 12.45, 25.55, 9.8,
       11.95, 3.75, 1.7, 11.3, 4153.2, 745.2, 480, 210, 754.9, 945, 421.2,
       637.2, 910.9, 1934.3, 14700, 29.5, 1386.6, 792, 1382.4, 5174.4,
       1393.2, 552, 1289.05, 599.05, 499.1, 11.6, 10, 5.85, 8.1, 5.7,
       40.05, 16.1, 48.25, 6.15, 10.85, 20844.6, 250, 264, 611.05, 63.7,
       127.4, 367.5, 499.8, 719.15, 552.25, 757.2, 16000, 200, 160, 11000,
       1293.6, 914.4, 2111.4, 6.3, 7.15, "'0.400000", 43.75, 1.9, 13.9,
       134.25, 13.5, 1.35, 18.15, 28.7, 59.85, 54.4, 2.8, 13.85, 4.65,
       35.9, 510, 799.1, 209.7, 2500, 2365.2, 1814.4, 71.1, 1062, 654,
       562.2, 1646.4, 246.15, 2434.55, 179.9, 1109.65, 2, 1658.4, 17,
       2689.2, 500, 1000, 852, 764.4, 1528.8, 1242.6, 339, 188, 960, 410,
       1884, 369.25, 600, 999.6, 492, 252.05, 182.65, 554.1, 1705.2, 282,
       479.2, 350.35, 382.2, 703.8, 5000, 10050, 184.6, 172.55, 552.8,
       142.1, 174.6, 179.95, 299, 958.8, 1044, 1080, 320, 2148, 646.9,
       125, 89.25, 1019.4, 161.2, 747, 2376, 1674, 11850, 176.05, 28.3,
       182.25, 447, 1896, 1237.5, 4410, 176.4, 29.75, 181.25, 214.2,
       899.05, 699.3, 3039.6, 7815.5, 442.5, 813, 85, 158.65, 178.15,
       37.95, 178.2, 192.2, 575, 124, 345, 138, 1285.1, 981, 523.6,
       218.85, 166.75, 28.95, 174.9, 90, 12500, 482.4, 35.1, 214.1, 184.5,
       179.75, 198, 1791, 510.6, 210.5, 174.35, 31.1, 182.4, 495, 523.85,
       35.15, 207.95, 168.95, 32.15, 60, 75.15, 1062.85, 401.65, 323.2,
       57.65, 424.4, 400, 1374, 1910.4, 4100, 450, 499.7, 28.35, 202.7,
       158.7, 26.35, 477, 1410, 185.55, 74.1, 154.9, 26.45, 172.7, 5850,
       1695.6, 1813.2, 520.65, 29.05, 200.4, 22, 172, 29.25, 178.7, 657,
       1128, 1776, 408, 29.8, 28.85, 200.85, 37.3, 167, 28.6, 184.95,
       1349.4, 900.6, 6500, 840, 29.95, 202, 44.75, 174.55, 181.65, 558.6,
       1144, 27.9, 199.1, 29.35, 175.1, 50, 29.1, 202.5, 29, 166.85, 28.8,
       176.35, 1366.9, 3325.2, 1490.4, 615.4, 801, 1706.4, 866, 1309,
       1009.8, 144.15, 678, 2256, 978, 75, 3456, 139.4, 527.15, 569.05,
       204.2, 171.4, 29.7, 172.85, 580, 108, 3002.4, 534.6, 1078.8, 1074,
       1818.95, 1008, 30, 252, 973.2, 29.6, 166.3, 174.85, 62.2, 804,
       1908, 599.85, 668.7, 1788, 201.35, 170.55, 294.8, 609, 169, 2030.4,
       940.8, 2268, 360, 53.1, 1073.4, 169.2, 330, 2000, 1361.7, 141.15,
       1827.3, 28.45, 2160, 131.1, 272, 162.65, 1251.6, 137.05, 256.2,
       1501.2, 143.2, 1422.2, 1392.3, 47.6, 798, 188.4, 90.5, 130.3,
       471.2, 838.8, 156, 233.8, 269, 2448, 361.9, 31.4, 128.4, 31.55,
       86.3, 133.05, 30.8, 31.65, 141.55, 102, 1020, 49, 397, 179, 350,
       469.9, 67.15, 180, 234.5, 204, 105, 39.6, 125.45, 536, 1.15, 95,
       446.7, 220.1, 265.35, 19.15, 124.3, 159, 568.8, 37.5, 1060.8, 3600,
       27.8, 1128.6, 1498.8, 133.55, 185.75, 13.45, 862.9, 152, 4677.6,
       1149.5, 2439.6, 2570.4, 1629.6, 65, 576, 2400, 136.95, 157.2, 39.3,
       864, 554, 237.6, 109, 996.2, 249, 761.25, 1676.65, 629.65, 208,
       128.9, 133.5, 834, 504, 533.95, 1714.25, 156.6, 26.65, 50.4,
       899.55, 303, 660, 872.2, 454.3, "'0.050000", 216, 190.5, 137.8,
       24.4, 43.4, 1071, 129, 278, 25.65, 356, 199, 819.3, 2136, 545,
       1423.55, 1160, 1337.05, 312, 222.5, 1500, 2698.7, 299.7, 134.55,
       70, 280, 1115, 1108.8, 420, 624, 465.5, 512.05, 696, 78, 39, 640,
       4530, 2750, 19776, 117, 725, 1740, 1440, 468, 4500, 51, 3420, 2088,
       2825, 8940, 24168, 77175, 11760, 2352, 9185, 6435], dtype=object)
```

As the column is called amount , it should contain no special character, including whitespace, except for the comma separator, which in this case is "."

To deal with the issue "'0.450000", etc, I tried:

```
df['amount'] = df['amount'].astype(str)
df['amount'] = df['amount'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('+-').rstrip('aAbBcC'))
df['amount']= df['amount'].replace("'", "")
df['amount']= df['amount'].replace("'0.000000", 0)
```

The steps above did not solve the issue.
The array should not have "'0.450000" but 0.45 , "'0.350000" but 0.35 , etc.

Comment: Please update the post to show the value of the array before you ran the code shown at the bottom.

Comment: updated the array as requested.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it has to do with float conversion

If you know every number is going to have only 2 decimals, you can string format them when you convert

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'floats': [0.5, 0.66, 0.]})

df['floats'] = df['floats'].apply(lambda x: "{:.2f}".format(x))
print(df)
```

=>

```
  floats
0   0.50
1   0.66
2   0.00
```

alternatively, if there is no absolute or given decimal limit and it's just trailing 0's you want to get rid of, do what you already do and then rstrip for 0

```py
df['amount'] = df['amount'].astype(str)
df['amount'] = df['amount'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('+-').rstrip('aAbBcC').rstrip('0').rstrip('.'))
# after stripping characters, strip 0's
# with SEPARATE rstrip, remove periods 
# (10.0000 => 10. without stripping periods)
# also why the '0' and '.' strip should be separate, 10.000 => 1 if you did .rstrip('0.')
df['amount']= df['amount'].replace("'", "")
df['amount']= df['amount'].replace("'0.000000", 0)
```

Comment: not sure if you would want to lstrip +-, since a negative amount would imply debt :)

Comment: I believe the first part of the solution is only useful if the column is already a float. 
"'0.450000" is not a float though..

The second part of the solution is close, but for some reason, this still remains: "ValueError: could not convert string to float: "'0.45"

Comment: also does it already consider if there is whitespace?

Comment: for the first solution, you would do the .map(lambda) instead of doing .astype(str). For the strip question, if you want it to include spaces but you're also giving it characters to strip, you have to include a space in the strip. ex: ```s='d d text'.lstrip('d ')``` => ```"text"```